# Typescript load module headache

Tags: typescript, module

I'm being stuck trying to understand module things in typescript lang with AMD (i'm using RequireJS); the jQuery.d.ts typings I've downloaded [from here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) contains the following lines at the end of the file:

```
declare module "jquery" {
  export = $;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

I'm trying to understand what's the most correct way to import the jquery module.

So far i'm using

```
import $ = require('jquery');
```

this seems to correctly load the jquery definition type (i've intellisense on $ object) and at the same time it generates the js:

```
define(["require", "jquery"], function(require, $) { ... }
```

so that requireJs can correctly download the library when need it.

1) Am I doing it right?

The [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) says that

> When importing a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import let = require("module") must be used to import the module.

But the [official lang spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1133-import-require-declarations) says:

> Import require declarations exist for backward compatibility with earlier versions of TypeScript.
>     ImportRequireDeclaration: import BindingIdentifier = require ( StringLiteral );

2) So is the syntax "import identifier = require (string) deprecated? Should I use instead

```
 import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

3) The [official lang spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1135-export-assignments) also says:

> Export assignments exist for backward compatibility with earlier versions of TypeScript. An export assignment designates a module member as the entity to be exported in place of the module itself.
>     ExportAssignment: export = IdentifierReference ;

4) So is the "export = $;" syntax in jquery.d.ts deprecated?

5) If i'd like to write my own "module", how can I import it  using a non-relative way? I wouldn't like to use:

```
 import * as mymodule from '../myfolder/mymodule';
```

Instead i'd like to use:

```
 import * as mymodule from 'mymoduleName';
```

Is there a way to do it? How should I declare my module? "declare module" syntax? "export =" syntax ? Something else?

6) Am I the only one who things this stuff (and the official docs) is really confusing?

Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I the only one who things this stuff (and the official docs) is really confusing?

No. I would argue the docs are wrong. I've been doing `import * as $ from "jquery";`.

## More

I've also raised your concern : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11340

Comment: Thank you basarat! By the way, i've already read your book TypeScript Deep Dive, that's a great work!!